# jQuery mobile button show only one word instead of two.. Why?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, button

My code:

```
<a data-theme="my-site" data-role="button" onClick="checkReachability()">Online Map</a>
```

And when I start an application I got only the button "Map" instead of "Online Map". I find it very strange. Just to mention that I'm jQuery Mobile beginner.

Application runs on Android phone.

The CSS:

```
.ui-btn-up-my-site { 
    color: white !important;
    text-overflow: initial;
    font-size:15px !important;       
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding-top:0 !important;
    margin-top:-25px !important;
    width:100px !important; 
    white-space: normal !important;             
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Include more of the surrounding markup and any relevant CSS.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gbcfs/) of what I get using the information you provided

Comment: OK, that helps.. But can you tell me how to remove that left and right padding in button? I tried like this but didnt work: http://jsfiddle.net/Gbcfs/6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20841/discussion-between-enrico-and-ivan-kovac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the font-size and width such that "Online Maps" doesn't fit on your button

```
font-size:15px !important;
width:100px !important;
```

You can either make your font smaller or make your button bigger. You can also make your button width depending on the width of the text using the following

```
display:inline-block;
# width: 100px !important; Comment out or delete this line.
```

See it in action - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gbcfs/7/)

As an aside, you should try to avoid using `!important`. Use CSS specificity and ordering to ensure the right styles are applied to the right elements instead.